# Question about convergence of series if $\{n a_n\} \to 0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

This is part of Rudin's PMA Exercise 3.14 (d). If I understand correctly, it would be helpful to prove the following:

> Let $a_n$ be some sequence. Assume that $\lim_{n\to\infty} na_n = 0$.

Prove that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k\,a_k}{n+1} = 0.$$

Comment: Use part (a) of the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reference: [Cesaro Mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean).

If $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}x_n=L$, then
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^nx_k=L.
$$

Apply this to $x_n=na_n$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\epsilon>0.$ There is some $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|na_n|< \epsilon $ for all $n>n_0.$ Then $$ \bigg|\sum_{k=1}^n ka_k \bigg|= \bigg|\sum_{k=1}^{n_0} ka_k + \sum_{k=n_0+1}^n ka_k\bigg| < \bigg|\sum_{k=1}^{n_0}ka_k\bigg| +(n-n_0)\epsilon$$

which leads to $$\limsup_{n\to \infty} \bigg|\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{ka_k}{n+1}\bigg| \leq\epsilon.$$

Since this is true for any $\epsilon>0$ we must have  $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{ka_k}{n+1}=0.$$

Comment: Great. You forgot the absolute value in the limsup inequality. And also, I think it is rather $\leq \epsilon$ there. Not a big deal, of course.

Comment: @julien Thanks.